# Writing temporary data from R

Tags: r

I want to write some temporary data to disk in an R package, and I want to be sure that it can run on every OS without assuming the user has admin rights.  Is there an existing R function that can provide a path to a temporary directory on all major OS's?  Or a way to reference a user's home directory?

Otherwise, I was thinking of trying this:

```
Sys.getenv("temp")
```

I presume that I can't expect people to have write access to their R locations, otherwise I could reference a path within the package directory: `.find.package("package.name")`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is: [`tempdir`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/tempdir).

This will return a session specific directory within the user's temp directory.  (So it gives the same value every time you call it within a specific R session.  Shut R and restart, and it will give you a different directory.)

[`pathological::temp_dir`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pathological/topics/temp_dir) provides a more user friendly wrapper.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Note to self: try apropos before asking a question: `apropos("temp")` would have returned `tempdir` and `tempfile`.

Answer (score -1):

After some further thought, I think that this should work:

```
path.expand("~")
```

That will give the home directory, which should have write access.

Comment: I would be more than a little annoyed if someone's code that I'm running started writing temporary files in my home directory.

Comment: In this case, these may be files that the user would want to keep, but I would give them the choice.  This is really about having a good default setting.  I'm going to use `tempdir` instead.